# C++:: Share class with all others class

Tags: c++, oop, class, share

I am new to OOP and C++.

I have a class called Database. The constructor of this class will establish connection to database. Then, I have others classes, like Users, Scores etc. I want all those classes shared the connection from Database class. How do I do that?

Example of Program flow:

- Main function called database class, which establish the connection to database.
- I want to authenticate user, like this:

  Users a("user1", "password1");
  a.authenticate("user1", "password1");

But in my Users::authenticate function, how do I make use of connection thats already established??

EDIT:

I am using mysql++ in c++

After read the answer, I will use the "pass as reference" method. But I encountered severals errors:

```
main.cpp

mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);    

int main() {
if (conn.connect(DATANAME, HOST, DBUSER, DBPASS)) {
    Users a(conn, "test","pass");
    a.authenticate();
```

This is my Users contructor and authenticate function:

```
Users.cpp

Users::Users(mysqlpp::Connection conn, string username, string password) {
    this->conn = conn;
    this->username = username;
    this->password = password;
}

void Users::authenticate() {
    if(this->conn != NULL){
        cout << "Have connection" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "No connection" << endl;
    }
}
```

it can compile and run. But it command line, it display:

```
Segmentation fault.
```

Any ideas why? I guess my code is wrong

Comment: Even though singleton pattern would *work*, I don't see why everyone is suggesting it. In the spirit of giving a bit of guidance, I would not recommend singleton unless you find that other patterns are causing distinct problems which point to singleton. Having multiple database connections open is not a problem (at very least, why would we assume it is?), so there should be no advantage singleton has over a simple global variable static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest passing in the connection to the other classes' constructors. For example:

```
Connection conn("servername");
User u(conn, "user", "pass");
```

This is an alternative to a static connection which others are suggesting. Both work fine but this pattern does not make the assumption that there is only one database connection in your running app.

Comment: Er, so the COnnection conn("server name") is the line where I connect to database?

Comment: Yes. In concept, a `User` requires a few inputs to be constructed - username and password, and also a database connection. With those three items, you can construct a `User` object; that's why 3 arguments to the constructor.

Comment: I see. My last question. Where should I disconnect the connection? At the end of main function?

Comment: Whoever establishes the connection should probably also be in charge of disconnecting it. Basically, after all dependent objects have been destroyed. If your connection object is a basic stack variable like in my code example, then you could even disconnect in the destructor, following the very common [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) design pattern.

Comment: +1 I prefer this to singleton, which is an anti pattern more often than not. A singleton will work here, but is probably not the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Database` object a singleton - see [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

The second solution that comes to my mind is simply giving refernece to `Database` object in constructor of `Users`, `Scores` etc.

Comment: Which method is better? I mean, in term of object oriented programming way.

Comment: Definitely the second one! Less coupling! Singleton is overused and should only be used with cross-cutting concerns, like logging, crash handling etc..

Comment: The first one. For example, if you need to add extra checks, or, lets say, choose from several connections, you can encapsulate this logic into singleton. But for simple apps the second one looks more appropriate.

Comment: @cpp_noob: I think it's dependent from how you want to use it. If you want to have few connections in your program (different for users, different for scores) the better solution is to give it as parameter. But if you have only one connection for the whole program I think singleton is better. But as you see, (Itlax comment) opinions are divided.

Comment: If you need to choose from several connections, the caller should do that, not the connection object. There is no reason to assume he needs some kind of dispatching logic (e.g. `GetDatabaseConnection(ConnectionPurpose p)` or something).

Comment: Huh... I am abit confused now. This is a simple app, which only have 1 connection. So, I should use singleton?? Hmmmm... confusing!!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your Users and Scores classes will need information about the database connection.  There are many ways of accomplishing this; here's a few.

1. You could have each Users and Scores object take in a pointer to an open Database object in their constructors.  That way, they can store the connection for later on and their member functions can reference the connection.
2. You could make the Database a singleton and then have the Users and Scores classes use its globally visible connection to read and write.  This seems like a suboptimal design because it forces all the objects in the program to use the same connection, though.
3. You could have the Database object export factory functions to create Users and Scores objects using it's connection.  This is essentially a variant on the first idea that makes the relations between the classes clearer and might simplify the logic for sharing the private connection status variables with the other objects.
4. You could modify the member functions of Users and Scores so that they take the database explicitly as an argument, allowing you to change the source of the data as you see fit.

In short, you have a lot of options.  Pick whichever you think is best for your particular application.

Comment: Thanks for providing several options for me. Seems like most gurus here are recommend using singleton. Could u post some sample code of using singleton in my case?

Comment: @cpp_noob- Given how little info you've provided aboutnthe structure of the code, I don't think I can provide anything useful.  However, it shouldn't be hard to code this up yourself; doing a Google search for singletons should provide some great resources.  Plus, you learn best by doing, so I'd suggest getting the experience of coding up a singleton firsthand!

Answer (score 1):

Without discussing whether the design you describe is good or not, what you whant to achieve is this:

```
class Database
{
public:
    DbConnection& Connection();

private:
    ...
};

class User
{
public:
    User(DbConnection& connection) : connection_(connection) { }

    ...

    void Authenticate()
    {
        ...
        connection_.Authenticate(username_, password_);
        ...
    }

private:
    std::wstring username_;
    std::wstring password_;
    DbConnection& connection_;
}
```

Comment: Where is the Database constructor? And what is that "DbConnection" thing? I am stuck at coding :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use static variable. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx

So you can access the same value from different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should use Singleton pattern for that. You can read about it in "Design Patterns" book by Gang of Four.

Comment: What if you want more than one connection?

Comment: For example, you can make a dispatcher singleton object that stores all connections and returns the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Connection as static; if your Database class has a Connection object, then:

```
static Connection connect;
```

You can access it via `Database::Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make the database class a singleton. 
However TDD practises say you should pass the database class to any class that needs to use it.

See here for Singleton example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/singletonrvs.aspx